# How to migrate WooCommerce to Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, database, migration, tools, woocommerce

I would like to migrate all data as possible to my Magento 2, I wish a module, code snippet or step-by-step tutorial.

It will be very useful, thank you!

Comment: did you get any idea?

Comment: Not yet @JenithSamuel

Comment: did you get any idea?

Comment: I used the litextension.com and it worked.